# how to unbrick android phone?

Tags: adb, unbricking, oppo-coloros

I have an Oppo N3 android phone and is now hardbrick. The cache and partition is formatted. Now I can only go inside recovery mode. ADB sideload not working because it stuck at 48%. Install from sd card also not working(Installation aborted). ADB shell not working(Device unauthorized). Cant flash using sp tools because do not have scatter file. If you guys have any idea what i should do is very much appreciated.

Comment: Finally able to unbrick my phone by using scattered file from her
https://dl.xda-developers.com/2/7/7/6/3/5/7/MT6582_Android_scatter.txt?key=7Vqw2AZI2l_CPI4L3R7AJg&ts=1506185255

Comment: Please post that as answer with little explanation, and mark your question as solved. Also, include the device name in question's title.